# PHP DOMDocument Get any element with attribute and the value

Tags: php

I am trying to get an element with attribute and the value. I've tried this:

```
public static function getElementByAttributeValue(\DOMDocument $domNode, $attribute, $value) {
    /** @var \DOMNode $node */
    foreach($domNode->childNodes as $node) {
        if($node->attributes && $node->attributes->length > 0) {
            $attrValue = self::getAttribute($attribute, $node->attributes);
            if($attrValue && strcmp($attrValue, $value) == 0) {
                return $node;
            }
        }
        if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            return self::getElementByAttributeValue($node, $attribute, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

this returns NULL even if the element is present in DOMDocument.
and I also tried this:

```
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($domNode);
    return $xpath->query("[@" . $attribute . "=\"" . $value . "\"]")->item(0);
```

the xpath->query returns false and it fails in getting ->item out of false.

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

Aah the second solution works fine but I need to do this:

```
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($domNode);
return $xpath->query("//*[@" . $attribute . "=\"" . $value . "\"]")->item(0);
```

Notice the `//*` before the xpath expression